# How to perform DCV for SSL in a secure namespace, using apache and django

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, domain-name

I have a django app being served by apache. It was configured and working by connecting to the raw IP of the server, but as the domain is .app I need to configure SSL to get it working with the domain I bought.

I am trying to complete Domain Control Verification (DCV), but I am running into this issue:

I can not serve the authentication file because my server can not use a secure connection. But I need to serve the file to get the certificate to have a secure connection. So I am stuck.

Here is where the file should be:

http://agileme.app/.well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt

I have disabled the usual django sites and enabled the following site to serve the file on port 80:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName agileme.app
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom.log combined
    <Directory /home/joe/DCV>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>


    DocumentRoot /home/joe/DCV
    Alias / /.well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt
</VirtualHost>
```

error when attempting to access from powershell:

```
> wget http://agileme.app/.well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt
wget : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust 
relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:1
+ wget http://agileme.app/.well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: 
(System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

new error (after fixing SSL redirect):

```
PS C:\Users\Joe\Documents\agileme\agileme> wget http://agileme.app/.well- 
known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt
wget : Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at agileme.app Port 80
```

but I know the file is here:

```
(agileenv) joe_blake8424@agileme-server:/home/joe/DCV/.well-known/pki- 
validation$ ls
fileauth.txt
```

and the DocumentRoot is set:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName agileme.app
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom.log combined

    DocumentRoot /home/joe/DCV

    <Directory /home/joe/DCV>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

thanks!

I had a VirtualHost in the 000-default.conf ALSO serving agileme:80 that was taking priority. Thanks all!!

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: to verify control of my domain, I have to serve a file at the URL posted. But when I try to access the file at that URL to check it is being served, it tells me that it is an unsecure connection.

Comment: And if I disable ssl (as in 'a2dismod ssl' ) i get the 'refused connection' error

Comment: You don't need to access the file yourself, whoever is doing the domain validation retrieves it. If you intend to test it, you need to use a command line tool, not your browser.

Comment: I run into the same issue verifying from powershell - error posted above

Comment: Is there a redirect to https happening? (If not, why is "wget" (powershell?) throwing a fit over tls when you seemingly access a plain http url)

Comment: Ok, so I did have an SSL redirect in 000-default.conf. Update above

Comment: You've posted two completely different `<VirtualHost>` blocks purporting to serve agileme.app on port 80. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: The latter one, I just removed the alias line. I thought I might need to use an alias because of the 'hidden' directory (.well-known)

Comment: I see no reason why that should give a 404. Have you checked the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys.

I had a virtual host in the 000-default configuration that was ALSO at agileme:80, so the host I set up to serve the DCV file wasnt doing anything.

Figured it out by changing the log file for that host, and seeing it not output anything.

Thanks!